# ImportError: No module named hmm

Tags: python, jupyter, gaussian, hmmlearn

I am trying to read this module on the Jupyter and I am getting this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1a818208e4fd> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.hmm import GaussianHMM
      2 
      3 
      4 def fit_hmm(depth_normed,  # normalised coverage array 
      5             transition_probability,  # probability of state transition

ImportError: No module named hmm
```

All I am trying to do is use this `from sklearn.hmm import GaussianHMM`.

I have these packages:

```
Python >=2.7
numpy >= 1.9.3 
scipy >= 0.16.0 
scikit-learn >= 0.16
```

I installed pip3 and installed the module again but it doesn't work.